# Diff percentage seems a bit off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, revisions-list, attribution

So I edited an answer originally by [P-Nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237688/p-nuts) by adding four carriage returns, since the answer was a big wall of text and I wanted to break it up with paragraphs. But SO says after the edit that I did 60% of the answer and marked me as the owner of the answer.

This is the answer that I edited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079335/experience-programming-with-netbooks-in-daily-commute/2079397#2079397

I believe there is something wrong with your diff algorithm. Since the change was only four characters long out of 803 characters. The change should be of 0.5% rather than 60%. It seems like SO thinks I removed 60% of the characters (which would be after the first carriage return) and replaced all of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Shog9 noted, you went from one line (no linebreaks) to three lines (two linebreaks).

You are not the "owner", FYI, you're just the person with the most edit strength on that post according to the algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

It's line-based and *extremely* simplistic. Presumably it stopped trying to find matches after the first paragraph and attributed the next two to you...