# simulation of legitimate activity by posting partial copies of prior answers

Tags: support, spam, answer-quality

I recently came across an interesting case of spammer account posting partial copies of prior answers in order to simulate legitimate activity. <sup>"look, not all my posts are about spam"</sup>

Even after I generally figured their trick, it turned out quite cumbersome to manually detect particular answer they've been copying from. Could there be a way to somehow automagically aid in that?

<sup>Kind of heuristic or diff capable to detect that particular answer is a partial copy of one of prior answers to the same question.</sup>

---

Those having sufficient privileges at Programmers can check the link to [example deleted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/difference-between-immutable-and-const/149585#149585) to find out more details on that particular case.

Note without providing an accurate, easy to verify reference to **from** where the answer was copied I would not even think about flagging spammer's stuff - since it looked pretty innocent in isolation.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux9KT.png]

Comment: And so [the AI boot cycle](http://xkcd.com/810/) begins...

Comment: This should be possible... most academic journals have a "similarity score" report that's automatically generated with each submission. Basically, any string of words that's present in a web search and scores above some threshold is shown to the editor and the reviewers. They can then check the high ranking ones to see if it is genuine plagiarism or accidental.

Comment: @yoda I only hope the algorithm wouldn't be like the one used to determine [majority contributors in CW posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130820/165773 "Klingon diff") :)

Comment: still not that hard to find, provided they are all under the same account; just click through and look at activity.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I am talking about finding answers **from** where the text has been copied; without justified pointing to these I would not even think about flagging spammer's stuff (it looks really legitimate)