# Show user reputation in Community Wiki (CW) posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, user-interface, community-wiki

Being [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) a *rough measurement of how much a user is trusted by the community*, I usually take a quick look (and with a pinch of salt) at the answerers' reputation when looking through the answers to a question I'm interested in.

Is there a specific reason why the user's rep is not shown on CW posts? Maybe it has something to do with an aspect of CW nature I'm not aware of?

Could we see it for instance in a tooltip or something?

[image]

Comment: CW posts are those that no longer belong to one person - they belong to the community. So, whose reputation do you expect to see there?

Comment: And the name on a particular post can be changed. The person with more edits will be named on the CW post.

Comment: @Oded Good point, I suppose I'd expect to see the rep of the user in the link below the revisions link (taking into account the link takes to the user's profile).

Comment: @oded, If I'm not mistaken, a question can become community wiki if it has more than 20 answers. A user herself can also just answer as community wiki. So being community wiki doesn't necessarily mean there have been many users collaborating on the answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz - there are several different mechanisms. Multiple edits, many answers and a request by the OP, for instance. The point is that once it has become CW, reputation shouldn't be attached to it anymore.

Comment: @Oded but - there's already a user attached to it, isn't it? I don't know if that user is the original poster or the one that most contributed to it, but it has a link to a user's profile anyway. Why not show that user's rep in a tooltip?

Comment: Because it is no longer **relevant**.

Comment: @Oded Wondering why is it relevant then to show that username with a link to his/her profile.

Comment: since [attribution in CW is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130820/165773), the guy under the post may be one who simply inserted most line breaks, or even one whose "contribution" has been totally rolled back (that's just the way _Klingon diff_ works). Because of this, popping up details to promote some random guy who just happened to be a target of such a (mis)attribution would be not fair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the text just above the username will send you to the edit history of the post which contains details about every edit made (and by which user).

[image]

In this view, you can see a user-card which includes the users profile picture, reputation and badge count.

[image]

As [Oded♦ mentions in his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210172/show-user-reputation-in-community-wiki-posts#comment673685_210172) it's unclear exactly what information you'll be able to get out of this "investigation". CW posts are authored by many users - you would have to inspect each edit to see what part was added by what user and then only after that look at the users reputation.

Comment: Indeed, and it's certainly valuable information. However, I was longing for a way to see rep without having to click away from the post.

Comment: But how would you display the rep of 38 users that made edits to the post? I really feel that this is too much info to be able to display in a popup/tooltip.

Comment: I think I've got my answer. Anyway I suppose I'd expect to see the rep of the user with the link below the revisions (seemingly the user that contributed more to the post - `sbi` with 31% of the post in the case of the example). Besides, it is already linking to a specific user.

Comment: @XaviLópez well he contributed most so he kinda deserves to have his name there. On the other hand, 69% of post is NOT from him - his rep is less than a 1/3 important ;) To answer if it's important let's round it to boolean... 0. Not important ;)