# Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange link migration Community Wiki post credit issue

Tags: discussion, migration, community-wiki, attribution

With the recent [migration of questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/633/796) to Meta Stack Exchange from Meta Stack Overflow, there's been an automatic rewrite of links across the various Stack Exchange sites.

It's good that links have been made current, but some MSO link-heavy Community Wiki posts like at https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/633/796 have had their ownership changed to "unknown" due to Community♦ making changes, taking the credit away from the primary author:

> [image]

I'm not sure how many posts this affects, so it may not warrant a specific fix, but I thought I'd report this anyway just so people know about it.

Comment: related: [Community wiki post not displaying majority author correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/community-wiki-post-not-displaying-majority-author-correctly) "Current diff algorithm makes CW posts look like contributors have been abducted by aliens..."