# Move the percentage below to avoid confusion in community wiki

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, users

Take a look at the image linked below.

[image]

I request that the percentage which is given in the second line "7 revs, 5 users 54%" be moved to 3rd line, such that the third line becomes "54% unknown".

This will make things more clear, as the % contribution is linked to the user in the third line accoring to Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158607/278826), even though the calculation algorithm seems to be faulty.

Comment: This can be fixed simply by sticking a `&nbsp;` between the `%` and the username.

Comment: That will move the user name up right?

Comment: That would in fact move the `54%` down.

Comment: Sorry, I have almost no knowledge in programming. Thanks for clarifying