# Why is the name for CW's different from the poster?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I just saw this CW answer:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/257207

Under the CW, it shows Shog9. However, Tim Stone is really the poster! Why is it showing Shog?

Comment: see also: [Diff percentage seems a bit off](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35972/165773)

Comment: @BillyMailman I added a bullet point about attribution to that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says `34% Shog9`:

[image: 34% Shog9]

It is telling you that Shog9 has done 34% of the work for that post.

Comment: Specifically, that Shog9 contributed more to that post than any other contributor.

Comment: +1 I can't miss with that THICK Red circle you marked