# Disregard automated edits from the Community user when calculating the authors percentage of a Community Wiki post

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, community-user, automatic-edits

Community Wiki posts show a "main author" and the percentage of the current post that is "theirs". The algorithm used to determine this percentage is old, (really old in internet years), and [rather simplistic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35973/361484). It basically determines the number of lines that were changed, and that is that. If you add a bunch of linebreaks at the top of the post you might get attributed almost the entire post.

This is all fair and well, except when posts get "hijacked" by the community user. A good example is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) post, where 47% of the post is attributed to an anonymous user, a.k.a. [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1). If you look at the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10249/revisions) you can see that Community came in thrice, revisions 4 to 6, which were all scripted edits.

If we were to disregard these changes either Sonic or animuson would be the most dominant author of the post, giving credit where it's due.

**Now for all of you saying this is too minor of a thing to fix I want to say this:**

We have had [dev time spend on making confetti](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/31/shipping-confetti-to-stack-overflows-design-system/?cb=1&_ga=2.227268126.2079616320.1622444651-336113274.1466066902). Then this can't be too minor.
 <sup><sub>Nothing to disrespect Aaron here though.</sub></sup>

Comment: I honestly doubt anyone is ever going to devote time to anything surrounding community wiki. At one point the discussion was completely removing community wiki from the sites, but I don't know where that ever ended up.

Comment: @animuson probably nowhere, as CW is still around. I think CW is still a valuable thing to keep. Personally I don't have any expectations what so ever that this will get any fixing, but still couldn't refuse to write this up, especially since confetti ;)

Comment: Apparently we removed it entirely for Teams in April 2020 and for public sites just backlogged it indefinitely. _shrugs_ But the day will likely come at some point in the future. It's a barely used feature that has almost no remaining purpose left due to other changes in the system that have occurred over the years and mostly just gets used for weird reasons we don't intend to continue supporting.

Comment: Good to know @animuson. I think its most important use cases are FAQ posts, and when a comment from a different user is converted into an answer. In both cases it feels unfair to reap the rewards of other users labour. If there is a different solution for those uses cases then by all means go ahead and remove the old CW.

Comment: @animuson I agree and it's a good point, but fact is, it's still in use, and thousands of people see it every day. Sure that this request is really minor, but it will make the experience a bit better.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the request excluding the edits suggested by *real* anonymous users (aka. users not logged in)?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT, not necessarily.  My intention was the automated edits, but if the by-effect is that real anonymous edits are disregarded as well that would be fine with me.